# Evaluate $\int_0^x t^{-1}(t^a+b)^{1/a}dt$

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to evaluate the following equation: $\int_0^x t^{-1}(t^a+b)^{1/a}dt$

The following is the results from Wolfram Alpha, but I cannot understand how to derive this.

[Results from Wolfram Alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXM4O.png)

There was a similar question to this problem:
[How this integral was evaluated using hypergeometric series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220842/how-this-integral-was-evaluated-using-hypergeometric-series)

Following the solution from this post, I have substituted $t=xu^{1/a}$ to get the following result:
$$\int_0^x t^{-1}(t^a+b)^{1/a}dt= b^{1/a}/a\int_{0}^{1}u^{-1}(\left(x^{a}/b\right)u+1)^{1/a}du$$

Setting d = -1/a, e = 0, f = 1, and z = $(-x^a/b)$ the integration part of the RHS of the above equation is equal to the integration part of the RHS of the following expression

$_2 F_1(d,e;f;z)=\frac{1}{B(e,f-e)}\int_{0}^{1}u^{e-1}(1-u)^{f-e-1}(1-zu)^{-d}du$

However, here $B(0,1)=\infty$, so this approach does not work. Do you know why this happens, and is there any other way to explain how the initial integral takes the hypergeometric functional form?

Comment: What is $\beta$, and is $F$ supposed to be $_2 F_1$?

Comment: @Accelerator Sorry $\beta $ was a typo, so I corrected it. And $F$ is $21$ (Sorry, I don't know how to write a subscript before a variable)

Comment: You can right-click on $_2 F_1$ and see what the LaTeX command is.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thank you for your comments. Can I ask what does that imply to this exercise? Does that mean this integration is not well-defined for some parameter values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5Bx%5E%28-1%29%28x%5Eu%2Bv%29%5E%281%2Fu%29%2Cx%5D) doesn't show the steps it means they aren't interesting.

On the other hand, we can peek inside some other database, for example that of [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org/integrationRules.html).

In particular, if we want to calculate:

$$
I_k(x) := \int x^{-1}\left(x^u+v\right)^{1/u}\text{d}x
$$

according to *Rubi Rule 272*, if $\frac{m+1}{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$ then:

$$
\int x^m\left(a+b\,x^n\right)^p\text{d}x = \frac{1}{n}\int y^{\frac{m+1}{n}-1}\left(a+b\,y\right)^p\text{d}y
$$

from which:

$$
I_k(y) = \frac{1}{u}\int y^{-1}(y+v)^{1/u}\text{d}y\,.
$$

So, according to *Rubi Rule 67*, if $b\,c\,d \ne 0 \, \land \, n \not\in \mathbb{Z} \, \land \, \left(m \in \mathbb{Z} \, \vee \, -\frac{d}{b\,c}>0\right)$ then:

$$
\int (b\,x)^m(c+d\,x)^n\text{d}x = \frac{(c+d\,x)^{n+1}}{d\,(n+1)\left(-\frac{d}{b\,c}\right)^{m}}\,{}_2F_1\left(-m,\,n+1;\,n+2;\,1+\frac{d\,x}{c}\right) + k
$$

we get what we want:

$$
I_k(y) = -\frac{\left(y+v\right)^{1+\frac{1}{u}}}{(1+u)\,v}\,{}_2F_1\left(1,\,1+\frac{1}{u};\,2+\frac{1}{u};\,1+\frac{y}{v}\right) + k
$$

i.e.

$$
I_k(x) = -\frac{\left(x^u+v\right)^{1+\frac{1}{u}}}{(1+u)\,v}\,{}_2F_1\left(1,\,1+\frac{1}{u};\,2+\frac{1}{u};\,1+\frac{x^u}{v}\right) + k\,.
$$

Comment: This can be an incomplete beta function  $B_y(a,0)$ or Lerch transcendent

Comment: @TymaGaidash Can I ask any reference that I can have a look?

Comment: @ChanKim See [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/01/0006/) and [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/05/0025/)